# numeric pyramid in java.

Tags: java

i need to print out a numeric pyramid using java. that counts in multiples of 2 along with the spaces like how it is below. but the code i have it only bring up multiples of 1 of no spaces.

```
                        1
                    1   2   1
                1   2   4   2   1
            1   2   4   8   4   2   1
        1   2   4   8   16  8   4   2   1
    1   2   4   8   16  32  16  8   4   2   1
1   2   4   8   16  32  64  32  16  8   4   2    1
```

this is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumericPyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Taking noOfRows value from the user

        System.out.println("How Many Rows You Want In Your Pyramid?");

        int noOfRows = sc.nextInt();

        //Initializing rowCount with 1

        int rowCount = 1;

        System.out.println("Here Is Your Pyramid");

        //Implementing the logic

        for (int i = noOfRows; i > 0; i--) {
            //Printing i*2 spaces at the beginning of each row

            for (int j = 1; j <= i*2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Printing j value where j value will be from 1 to rowCount

            for (int j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++) {
                System.out.print(j+" ");
            }

            //Printing j value where j value will be from rowCount-1 to 1

            for (int j = rowCount-1; j >= 1; j--) {                 
                System.out.print(j+" ");             
            }                          

            System.out.println();

            //Incrementing the rowCount

            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
How Many Rows You Want In Your Pyramid?

7

Here Is Your Pyramid

              1 

            1 2 1 

          1 2 3 2 1 

        1 2 3 4 3 2 1 

      1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 

    1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1

  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: What would happen if every time you increase `j` by one, you double it instead?  And every time you decrease `j` by one, you halve it instead?

Comment: what do you mean?.

Comment: @DavidWallace I see what you did there  (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°), OP does (sadly) not

Comment: You might want to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

For each j from 1 to n you need write 2^j. Currently you are writting only j.
So write function which for given k returns 2^k.

**EDIT: For bigger n you need to use BigInteger:**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class NumericPyramid {
    private static BigInteger pow(int exponent) {
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
        for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
            result = result.multiply(two);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and use it in both for loops. Replace

```
System.out.print(j+" ");
```

with

```
System.out.print(pow(j)+" ");
```

Comment: Wouldn't `1 << j` be easier than implementing an entire `pow()` method? And the parameter to `pow()` is not the *base*, but the *exponent*. The base is hardcoded to 2.

Answer (score 0):

the pyramid goes 1 2 4 8 16, that's a sequence of 1 * 2 = 2, 2 * 2 = 4, 4 * 2 = 8 and so on, and then goes inverse, 8 / 2 = 4, 4 / 2 = 2, 2 / 2 = 1, you only need to multiply by 2 and divide by 2 when the center

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            int cont = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(cont + " ");
                cont = cont * 2;
            }
            cont = cont / 2;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                cont = cont / 2;
                System.out.print(cont + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: What is the point of `i * 2 / 2`? It's the same as `i`. Multiplying by 2 then dividing by 2 leaves the original number (unless it overflowed).

Comment: You need to add the spaces so it takes the form of a Pyramid